# Angular, Keycloak, and SSO Automatic login with angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, keycloak, implicit-flow, angular-oauth2-oidc

We are attempting to create the following setup within our environment...
Angular 4.4+ application which uses Keycloak as the authentication server which has AD Federation and Kerberos support.  This is to provide our intranet users with a true SSO experience for our internal web applications.

Flow:

1. User navigates to application
2. Application checks for valid token on hand in localStorage
3. launch initImplicitFlow if no valid token
4. Server and Client browser so a Kerberos negotiation instead of showing a login screen
5. Redirect back to the application after successful negotiation just as if the user had entered correct credentials.
6. Application checks for valid token in response (this is the murky part), saves tokens and user roles to localStorage, and routeguards now allow navigation in the application.

I tried to get the following sample to do the automatic login initiation, but cannot seem to get it to work.  Can anybody look at this sample and see where to put the initImplicitFlow call to make this work?  I've tried so many different things that I cannot even keep them straight.

Reference Project - https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/tree/master/sample/src

Thanks for any help or guidance on this.

Comment: Hope you have solved this. If so please share the code, how the post login will make redirect.

Comment: In the auth.config for the client you need to supply a /callback url (you can name it whatever you want) which routes in your angular app to a "callback" component.  This callback component does a handleAuth routine which checks for the token and subsequently does all the local storage saving.

Comment: I hope to have a new angular scaffold of a project that has all of this baked in within the next couple of weeks.